# How to stop backslash working on XAMPP

Tags: apache, linux, windows, xampp

I have XAMPP installed on my **Windows** development machine and I always use **Linux** production machines.  The most common mistake I make is to use a backslash for filespec.  Either slash  works on Windows, but the **backslash** fails on Linux.

Is there a way to stop the backslash from working on XAMPP on my Windows machine ?

Comment: Which directives in particular do you have an issue with?

Comment: I was enquiring if there was an option in any of the apache ini files to stop backslash from working.

Comment: "use a backslash for filespec" - Are you referring to URLs or Apache directives? (If URLs, which browser(s) are you testing?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Backslashes in file-paths in Apache directives

As far as I know, there is no option in *Apache* to prevent Apache/Windows from interpreting the backslash as a directory separator.

However, it is recommended to not use the backslash as a directory separator (on Windows) as you can get conflicts with backslash-escapes on certain directives. From the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/platform/windows.html#cust):

> - The directives that accept filenames as arguments must use Windows filenames instead of Unix ones. However, **because Apache may interpret backslashes as an "escape character" sequence, you should consistently use forward slashes in path names, not backslashes**.

Any directive that takes an absolute file-path is unlikely to work unaltered on Linux anyway.

You just have to remember to always use forward slashes I'm afraid.

---

#### **UPDATE:** Backslashes in the URL-path

If, however, you are talking about the use of unencoded backslashes in the URL-path then you can do *something*, however...

- AFAIK, there is no configurable option in Apache itself to disable unencoded backslashes in the URL-path.
- You can block *encoded* backslashes (ie. `%5C`) in the URL-path by setting the following in the server config (not `.htaccess`):

  ```
  AllowEncodedSlashes Off
  ```

  This will result in such URLs returning a "404 Not Found". However, `Off` is the default, so unless this has been explicitly enabled already in the server config, then you do not need to do this.
- Later versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari (and reportedly Edge and IE) automatically convert any unencoded backslashes in the URL-path to (forward) slashes *before* making the request to your server. So your server never actually sees the backslash. Consequently, this means that these backslashed-URLs (that the user might request) will work just the same on Windows and Linux in these browsers (because there is no backslash reaching the server).

  Further reading (although a little dated):
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438008/different-behaviours-of-treating-backslash-in-the-url-by-firefox-and-chrome
- Strictly speaking a literal backslash character is not valid in the URL-path portion of the URL and should be URL-encoded (%-encoded) as `%5C`. Other browsers "should"<sup>***1**</sup> URL encode the backslash in the request, so these requests should be blocked by default anyway in these other browsers (by the default `AllowEncodedSlashes` state as mentioned above).

  <sup>(***1** I say "should" since modern browsers tend to auto-encode the requested URL as required when making the request, although strictly speaking this is something the user/developer should be doing explicitly.)</sup>

**Blocking unencoded backslashes in the URL-path**

If the unencoded backslash is actually reaching your server then you can use the following mod_rewrite rule at the top of the `.htaccess` file (or server config) to block requests that contain a backslash in the URL-path portion of the requested URL.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Send a "400 Bad Request" if backslash in requested URL-path
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "\s[^?]*\\"
RewriteRule ^ - [R=400]
```

Note that we need to check against `THE_REQUEST` in the *condition* above. The URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (and the `REQUEST_URI` server variable) are pre-processed and have already had backslashes converted to (forward) slashes! So the backslash cannot be matched using these other methods.

<sup>(Tested using CURL against a Windows and Linux server.)</sup>

Comment: You couldn't write a `RewriteRule` to give an error for a backslash in a URL?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I'm not sure what you mean? Yes, you could check for a backslash in the URL, but I believe the OP is wondering how to prevent the use of the backslash as a directory separator in the Apache config directives, eg. `DocumentRoot C:\xampp\vhosts\example.com\public_html`.

Comment: The way I interpret their problem is that Apache on Windows accepts backslashes in the URLs.  They are using this as their development environment.  Then when they go to release to production, they find that URLs that worked in dev don't work in production.  If there were a mechanism to have Apache on Windows return an error for such URLs, they would be able to catch the problem early (as soon as they create a link with a backslash, not once they release to production).

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Hhmm, could be. I wonder what browser(s) the OP is using to test? Chrome, Firefox and Safari appear to automatically convert any backslashes in the URL-path to (forward) slashes _before_ making the request, so "backslashed" URLs will "work" in these browsers on both Windows and Linux. (I had to use CURL to test the above.) I've updated my answer.

Comment: Firefox didn't backslashes to forward slashes at one point, but this was asked about 10 years ago: [Different behaviours of treating \ (backslash) in the url by FireFox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438008/different-behaviours-of-treating-backslash-in-the-url-by-firefox-and-chrome) -- and I see you already included this link, so you know that. but I hadn't realized that Firefox had changed at some point.

Comment: @MrWhite I am using Chrome and Brave to do my initial test.  But from the production sever I am using firefox, native samsung, native android as well.   I realise now, that Its not the slashes in the url that are a problem.  Its internal paths to things like php and delphi files.   I may have to write a scanner to check things, once the sites get busy.  Maybe I can find something that will check it in GIT.

Comment: @RohitGupta In that case you are at the mercy of the OS. Keep your file paths in a separate config file so you don't need to search all your scripts (avoid hardcoding anything) and/or pass your file-path through a function that normalises the file-path - this is often necessary on Windows if you are deriving the file-path from system vars that can return mixed slashes.